# Check whether a service from Services menu is available

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, service

I'm trying to programmatically call a Service from Cocoa application using [code]NSPerformService[/code] call. But I want to know whether the service is available before calling the API. Is there a way to query the status of the Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grab the array of MenuItems in the Services menu of your app to check which services are currently available. Of course this list will change based on the selection in your app. The code snipped below will show you how to come there assuming the Services menu exists.

```
    let mainMenu = NSApplication.shared.menu
    let serviceMenuItems = menu?.items.first?.submenu?.item(withTitle: "Services")?.submenu?.items
    print("ServiceMenu Items: \(serviceMenuItems)")
```

Have fun.